# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null(...) on Onepage checkout page

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, javascript

I can't progress to the payment step when I click continue:

> UncaughtTypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null : getting
>   error on click continues button.

Can someone assist me, please?

[image]